# DB2 V10 zOS JDBC getting SQLCODE -302

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, zos

I'm trying to execute a query against z/OS DB2 using JDBC Type 4 Connection. The query is simplified:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ? = ' ' OR NAME = ?");  
    stmt.setString(1, "Joe");  
    stmt.setString(2, "Joe");
```

Running this Query will result in an SQLCODE -302 because `Joe` is length three and one blank is length one.

If I chnage the Query to

```
"SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ? = '   ' OR NAME = ?"
```

it runs without error but that is not what I'm looking for.
Is there maybe a JDBC property which makes the expression `?=' '` universal for any length of the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no information in the bare parameter marker as to the exact data type or precision of the parameter, the DB2 server uses the right side of the expression to determine it. You could use an explicit cast to provide the necessary information to the query compiler:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE cast(? as varchar(10)) = ' ' OR NAME = ?"
```

Replace `varchar(10)` with the actual data type of `EMP.NAME`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This basically works but I'm still not free of changing the data type of the column eg from `CHAR(10)` to `CHAR(20)` without changing all the programms using the column in that way.

Comment: Firstly, if you are forced to change the column data types in an existing database, there's something wrong with your design approach. Secondly, nothing prevents you from casting the parameter marker to a data type that covers your future DDL exercises, e.g. VARCHAR(32672).